# How to adjust Datagridview column width and size depends on screen size webform?

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms

I am using asp.net c# webform and i am using datagridviews , I searched and i found the property in windows form

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

But in web form this property not used. 
How can i make my datagridview dynamically change columns width and size when open my website from mobile or ipad window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week of trying I found the following solution and its working correct on mobile screen by adding scroll bar and width = 100% to the div and put datagridview also in div ,this is the code i used :

```
<div style="overflow:scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHome" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewHome_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="30" ShowFooter="True">

               <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width:100%"> <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"  NavigateUrl='<%#"/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id=" +Eval("Request number")+"&DEPT ID=" +Eval("DEPT ID")+"&Test Id=" +Eval("Test Id")+"&Culture=" +Eval("Culture")%>' runat="server">Print Result</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient MRN#</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="width:100%">  <asp:Label ID="lblpatient" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient No") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient Name</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient Name") %>'></asp:Label></div> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Order Number</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request number") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Test No.</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblrepd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Test Id") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                 <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Test Name</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="LblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Test_Name") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>To</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="refhigh" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("High Range") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Text Range</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="textrange" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text Range") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Request Date</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="width:100%">  <asp:Label ID="lblreqd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request Date") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Result Date</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblrepd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Report Date") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>








            </Columns>

            />


        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```